# Unwanted content in website title

Tags: jquery, title

I use "anythingslider" jquery plugin to animate some html content in my wordpress theme.
and i use this code in header.php to show title:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) ?><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

But the first page have unwanted content (#&panel1-2) in title like this:
www.domain.com/#&panel1-2

I am sure this is because of anythingslider plugin but i don't have any idea how to fix this.

Comment: Why are you sure it is the slider? Does this go away when you disable that plugin?

Comment: I am sure because when i disable this plugin the problem disappear.

Comment: Is your title rewritten if you turn off Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt WordPress would be putting a url like you mentioned 'www.domain.com/...' in title tags either way. Are you sure you're that's where it's showing up?

The hash in the url is likely just for slider functionality. You could try a different slider or ignore it, since it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: i am afraid this problem affect on url seo

Comment: Can you post a link to where it's happening?

Comment: the link is homepage

Comment: when a slide change it change the unwanted part at the end of link like:#&panel1-2   #&panel1-1

Comment: Right, the #&panel1-2 is showing in your address bar not in the title tags. Do some research but I don't believe this affects SEO.